# Train connections after ferry Borkum-Eemshaven

Tags: germany, netherlands, ferries, timetables, nederlandse-spoorwegen

I would like to take the ferry from Borkum to Eemshaven and continue to Groningen in March. Comparing the [ferry timetables](https://www.ag-ems.de/fahrplan) and the [train departure](https://www.ns.nl/) times it appears to me that they are exceptionally poorly timed, given that the only reason for passenger trains in Eemshaven is connecting to the ferry.

There is a ferry at 8:20, arrival Eemshaven 50 minutes later, while the next train is at 11:48, implying over 2.5 hours waiting time.
Even worse, the 11:30 ferry may arrive just after the 11:48 and 12:18 trains, with the next train only leaving at 17:48.

Am I missing something? Or do I have to accept the long layover?

*Ferry search result*
[image]

Comment: I don't see any 8:20 ferry in the [timetable](https://cdn.ag-ems.de/fileadmin/AG_EMS/6_Download-PDF/AGE/2024/AGE_FP_24_web_Flyer.pdf)

Comment: @NicolasFormichella thanks for the link, hadn’t seen that one yet, it seems to contradict the information on the website (see question update), but doesn’t change the question per se

Comment: I can't read Dutch, and that timetable is awfully cryptic for me (it's linked in the [English](https://www.ag-ems.de/en/schedule)... for some reasons)

Comment: … got it, the pdf includes the bus/train on the island, hence the earlier departure

Comment: Strange, until March 14, the ferry departs at 10.30 which seems to align better with the train. I wonder if train times will change then, too. Maybe you should contact Arriva about that. The [Arriva travel planner](https://www.arriva.nl/plan-je-reis/reisplanner/) won't let you select a date after 13-02

Comment: I did run the search on the German railsite and they advice a connection via Leer Germany, search for Bahn dot de for that planner. I also assume seasonal changes.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for checking! I think that's just because bahn dot de is not aware of the Borkum-Eemshaven ferry connection (it also sends me through Leer when searching for the route "Borkum to Eemshaven", which is clearly not reasonable).

Comment: @Berend Thank you, well spotted! Yes, I think I will contact Arriva. I already asked the Borkum tourist information and they find this as odd as I do.

Comment: Okay, keep us informed if you find out anything

Comment: Those ferries to the Frisian islands run through tidal flats. The times they announce online are only rough estimates because of the different tides each day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the timetables are simply not up to date yet.

Arriva's answer (my translation): "These are indeed the times for now and will probably be different later in March. Since this is variable it is best to plan your trip shortly in advance to see if more times have been added."

This is consistent with the observation that the Arriva Travel Planner only shows dates a month or so in the future, as pointed out by @Berend.

As for the ns.nl timetables... I guess they are just making heroic extrapolations.

Comment: Did Arriva send a link/image with the new updated times?

Comment: @JorenVandamme, no, the translated text in my answer is all I got.